# SVN Server / repository on remote webhost?

Tags: php, apache, svn, tortoisesvn

My wish is pretty simple, yet so complex, aparrently.

As a programming-student, I was introduced to SVN, TortoiseSVN to be exact.
We were given a url to the repository, which looked something like:
www.schoolderp.com/svn/project1

That is great and all, but now we want to get some private projects going.
So with TortoiseSVN we created a repository, uploaded it to a webhost and tried to view it through the repo-browser.. Ofcourse it couldnt be that simple.. bah!

So for the last couple of days, i've searched the web for answers, but im stuck.

I've read alot of places that Apache is needed, but when I read about Apache, it seems that it is a service i need to run on my machine, or am I just stupid?

So atm i pretty much going insane, and would LOVE a really simple explanation on what to do, to get a svn server up and running on my webhost :/

Thanks alot in advance..

Comment: I am still unclear about what this question is asking for. You uploaded to the webhost, and tried to view it through the repo-browser, but it did not work? What answer are you looking for? Are you looking for a way to view the source files online? Or do you want to learn about hosting a svn server?

Comment: TortoiseSVN is a SVN CLIENT as far as I know. You can't create new repositories using it. You have to have access to svn server to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a server (virtual or real) to run svn. A simple webhost does not provide the features needed for an svn server. 
As an alternative there are several svn servers where you can have your own private repositories.

[SVN Hoster](http://www.origo.ethz.ch/)

Comment: That sucks, but explains why I have been having so much trouble..
Didnt even realise that a webhost isnt equal to a actual server..
Just shows my ignorance.. :P

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You will need a root privilege if you want to setup svn server. However, you can use some other free svn hosting services and can see the source files on the web just like a repo-browser.

http://unfuddle.com/

Comment: It's my own webhost, as in im paying for it, so I got root privilege.
But creating a repository in the root wont work.

Comment: Do you have a Dedicated or VPS ?

Comment: Having your own webhost does not mean you have a root privilege.

Answer (score 0):

if you're running some private ones, and don't have access to a VPS or Dedicated server (and your educational institution can't help you set this up on one of their departmental IP addresses), then perhaps one solution may be to use VisualSVN for Windows (Assuming you're using windows).  With this you can set up the Repositories on a PC that you're using (or Laptop) and then use something like dyndns (or another dynamic name/ip mapping service) to map your PC/Laptop's IP to a webdomain like oursvn.yourwebsite.com.  With some configuration, you can get your SVN server to be accessible (even on a portable laptop) from a url that maps to your 'current' ip address.

This may not be a simple route to go down, but it's a low cost, DIY route.

VisualSVN ( http://www.visualsvn.com/ ) is relatively easy to set up.  Dynamic IP/url mapping services can be free or paid and if you create your users and repositories in VisualSVN, you can have control over the accesses yourself. (Download the server version on the right if this is a solution you think would suit.)

Failing that, there are third party service providers who can offer you SVN hosting for a range of prices.

http://beanstalkapp.com/pricing [not a recommendation, just as an example reference]

http://dyn.com/dns/dyndns-free/ [again also not a recomandation, just an example]

Comment: I just tought that I would be able to use my own webhost instead, apparently not..

Thanks for the alternatives..

Comment: Hi Tsanas - you could ask your webhost to install Git or SVN on your hosting for you (if it's VPS or Dedicated). Often costs are prohibitive, but there are some solutions around that are worth considering for this, or considering moving hosts to one that supports it out of the box.  IT is much easier to let them set it up than for you to manage it.

Answer (score 0):

SVN-repo and website are weakly related in common

1. Dreamhost offer SVN inside it's ordinary hosting package
2. You can use any (free or not) SVN-hosting
3. You can create locale repo (with TSVN) and use file:// protocol for access (only locally)
4. You can create local repo and power it by svn:// protocol (networkable) with svnserve

Answer (score 0):

Apache is just one of the ways of hosting a Subversion repository. Subversion uses three protocols for serving its repository:

- http: (and https:)
- file:
- svn:

The simplest is `file:`. All you have to do is create a repository on your local machine, and simply point to it using the `file:` protocol. Download [SlikSVN](http://www.sliksvn.com/en/download). This is a command line driven client, but it includes the `svnadmin` command that you can use to create repositories:

```
C:\repository> svnadmin create myrepos
```

Now, in TortoisSVN, point to not ***`http`***`://www.schoolderp.com/svn/project1`, but ***`file`***`://C/repository/myrepos`. Note the different protocol used! You should be able to checkout from your newly created `myrepos` repository. (It will be empty, so there won't be any files or directories there, but you can create them and check them back in.

The problem with the `file:` protocol is that you have to be on the local system and it doesn't really handle multiple users very well. But, if you're using TortoiseSVN, and its your own private project, it works pretty well.

The other possibility is to use `svnserve` to run the repository using the `svn:` protocol. This is actually faster than `http:` because there's less overhead, but you can only have a single repository per server instance while with http, you can have multiple repositories running on a single Apache httpd instance.

```
C:\repository> svnadmin create myrepos
C:\repository> notepad myrepos\conf\svnserve.conf
C:\repository> notepad myrepos\conf\passwd
C:\repository> svnserve -r myrepos -d
C:\repository>
```

The `myrepos\conf\svnserve.conf` file is the configuration file for your repository. You'll need to change the line that says `###password-db = passwd` to remove the `###` from the beginning of the line. This sets the password database to the passwd file.

You'll need to create the passwd file. There's a sample one you can use as a template. All you need is to add under the `[users]` section the name of the user and their password. For example: `david = swordfish` would set user `david`'s password to `swordfish`.

Now, you can point TortoiseSVN to ***`svn`***`://localhost` and check out from your repository. Your friends can also checkout from the same repository substituting your machine name for `localhost`.

So, you have to create a Subversion repository, but it's pretty easy to do with the `svncreate` command. And you can immediately access it via the `file://` protocol without doing anything else. If you want to share this repository with other people, you need to use the `svnserve` command to run the SVN server, but that's also pretty easy to do.

I recommend that you go through the [Subversion online manual](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/). The first few chapters will give you a basic understanding of how Subversion works and how to use the Subversion `svn` command which is part of the SlikSVN client you downloaded and installed. The server fundamentals are in [Chapter 5](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.6/svn.reposadmin.html) and information about using [svnserve is in chapter 6](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.6/svn.serverconfig.svnserve.html).